# Is there a way to sign my code or secure it?

Tags: java, security

I am a java beginner anyway, I have written this program that formats Military time that java returns to normal time, for example 1:01 PM instead of 13:01:00. To get to the point I ust created a blog a tumblr and I want to share this code and I know it sounds silly and sellfish but I want to learn to secure my code or stamp it somehow so people dont steal it?

Comment: you want to share code and also want to prevent anybody from using/copying it? Of course you have the copyright as the creator, but honestly, if the code is once out there in the internet you have hardly any possibilities to prevent anybody from just copying it.

Comment: If everyone took this view then SO wouldn't exist, and that would make me sad

Comment: given that all your program does is +12 if PM and add `:00`, there isn't really anything to protect. But more generally, rely on the licenses. There's no way to reliably protect any code. Anyone could copy an entire book if they had the inclination and time. Other than that, consider why you're releasing it: if you want people to improve it (thus doing work for you) put as few restrictions on it as possible. Maybe public domain or lesser GPL.

Comment: @wakjah not only SO, the whole open source scene - but closed source is viable to survive too - best example: Microsoft. They lend big parts of their first OS from a thrown away code from IBM as rumor has it

Comment: You shouldn't worry about that. At least not before you can write code that's worth copying/stealing, which should take several years.

Comment: Again 'am new to java and programming. and what I have done for "restrictions" as Dave mentions is make my fields my private and my constructor is private so the only way you can construct the object is through getInstance() method and am not sure if thats what u meant by restrictions

Comment: You have copyright already. Unfortunately with something this trivial,  proving that someone copied your code, is going to be difficult. Unless you wrote it in way that nobody sane would copy anyway???

Comment: private / protected / etc. in the code is really about idiot-proofing it. It has nothing whatsoever to do with how easy it is to copy (or even decompile if you release only compiled code). Certainly worth doing to make your library more usable, but you should always know *why* you're doing something! The restrictions I was talking about are legal restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big question. It depends from the legal framework of your country.

Generally speaking you can start the long process to **patent your system**, but the simple code has not change (work around excluded) and it is quite expensive (for my [patent](http://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/WO2011001457) we spent 12K€ more or less).

**In Italy we have SIAE**: we pay 120€ and we send a CD to an authority; the code will be protected for 5 years, but if a guy change the 20% of the original code .. it is another code.